# How to delete a cell in a section using custom action?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delete-row

ive been struggling too delete my cells in the tableview using `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` I have it set up to where you swipe the cell the delete image shows up and an alertView shows when the delete image is pressed and asks if you want to delete the row. But once yes is pressed the cell doesn't get deleted/removed

```
import UIKit

class CartViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedProduct: ItemList!       // allows data to be passed into the CartVC

    // allows data to be sepearted into sections
    var cartItems: [CartItem] = []
    var groupedItems: [String: [CartItem]] = [:]
    var brandTitle: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        groupedItems = Dictionary(grouping: cartItems, by: {$0.itemList.brandName})
        brandTitle = groupedItems.map{$0.key}.sorted()
    }
}

extension CartViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return brandTitle.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let brand = brandTitle[section]
        return groupedItems[brand]!.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cartCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartCell") as! CartCell

        let brand = brandTitle[indexPath.section]
        let itemsToDisplay = groupedItems[brand]![indexPath.row]
        cartCell.configure(withCartItems: itemsToDisplay.productList)

        return cartCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cartHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartHeader") as! CartHeader

        let headerTitle = brandTitle[section]
        cartHeader.brandName.text = "Brand: \(headerTitle)"

        return cartHeader
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 45
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cartFooter = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartFooter") as! CartFooter

        let brand = brandTitle[section]
        let subtotal = groupedItems[brand]?.map { $0.getCartTotal() }.reduce(0, +) ?? 0
        cartFooter.cartTotal.text = String(subtotal)

        return cartFooter
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 150
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let edit = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (action, view, nil) in
            let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Deletion", message: "Are you sure you want to remove this item from cart? ", preferredStyle: .alert)

            refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

            }))

            refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                refreshAlert .dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))

            self.present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        edit.backgroundColor = .red
        edit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "best_sellers")
        let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [edit])
        config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
        return config
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related, but it's always recommended to avoid multiple `Array`s for the datasource of a table view and using `Dictionary` to feed the table view is not a good idea. You should create a `Model` type.

Comment: @nayem it took me a long time to figure out how to create those arrays to make my cart work. but you're correct the more I look at it the more I see how right you are. But im more confused in how to transition it into your way or another possible method to do so. I just posted up a question asking for help  to solving this if you wouldn't mind looking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558904/how-to-fix-the-separation-collections-of-cells-in-my-sections-in-my-tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS checks the number of rows before and after a delete operation, and expects them to add up correctly following the change.In your alert action you need to delete your current object.

```
refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
             tableView.beginUpdates()
             // brandTitle[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row) // or you can directly use this

              let brand = brandTitle[indexPath.section]                                        
                 groupedItems[brand]!.remove(at:indexPath.row)
                   tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                   tableView.endUpdates()
         }))
```

Comment: im getting two errors in ```groupedItems[brand]!.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)```
                   and ```groupedItems.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: nil)``` the errors are Value of type '[CartItem]' has no member 'removeAtIndex' and Value of type '[String : [CartItem]]' has no member 'deleteRowsAtIndexPaths' and my apologies I accidentally submitted before writing out the thing

Comment: it works successfully at deleting the cell but also deletes the header and footer with it. which is fine if the section has only one cell in it, but if it has multiple items and one cell is deleted than it loses its header footer for all the cells in the section if that makes any sense